# How do i compare the "EndDate" in my database to the current date of today?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to execute query depending on if EndDate is < Today's date.Here is what i have so far, i need to know how to compare them Thanks!

```html
//Delete from DB Condition (EndDate)
        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteByDate", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        Clear();
```

this is the stored procedure.

```html
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteByDate]
@AdvID int
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE a SET a.Status = 0
    FROM Advertisement a
    WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID
END
```

Comment: Where is the stored procedure?  Please add it to the question

Comment: What is DeleteByDate ?

Comment: I think I already added the comparison on your previous post, if the comparison based on textbox value against `DateTime.Today`/`DateTime.Now`.

Comment: When endDate has passed by Current date, it should set status to 0. But like i said, i have no idea how to retrieve the data from DB to compare to current date

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it from C# or SQL like this :

C#

```
if(EndDate < DateTime.Now.Date)     // Assuming EndDate is already defined in your class 
{
    using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlCon.ConnectionString) )
    using(SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteByDate", sqlCon))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@AdvID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@AdvID"].Value = AdvID //Assuming it's already defined;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   
    }   
}
```

SQL :

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[DeleteByDate]
@AdvID int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = GETDATE() -- to get current date

    -- Assuming that Advertisement table has the column EndDate
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Advertisement a WHERE a.EndDate < @CurrentDate )
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE a SET a.Status = 0
        FROM Advertisement a
        WHERE a.AdvID = @AdvID  
    END 
END
```

If you go with C#, it won't fire the sp until the condition is met, but in SQL, it'll make your C# fires the sp, and the sp will check the condition every time your code runs it.

So, it depends in your application structure, is it application first, or database first, which comes first would be your way to go.

Comment: hi, im getting an error that says "Procedure or function 'DeleteByDate' expects parameter '@AdvID', which was not supplied." Is there a way to check the Database ID itself instead of retrieving the ID and delete?

Comment: @JiaHao my bad, I forgot the parameters, fixed as well. About your question, why you don't do a computed column on Status column, which will check the EndDate column with the GETDATE(), which will update your status automatically.